# Resume cut-and-paste/copy in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to move some big file from harddrive to a removable drive. I am using mv.

However sometimes for some other reason, the operation might fail in the middle of running. Is a way that can resume the cut-and-paste operation from where was left last time?

Comment: How big is the file?  What operating system are you using? OS X? Linux?  What are the reasons that the move operation fails?

Comment: It fails because the transfer causes too much heat to the CPU in my old laptop. The file is around 1.1G. Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy is easy. Use `rsync --partial` instead. Don't think there's a solution for a move though.

Comment: Do the copy then a remove after it is successful to simulate a move!

Comment: can rsync --partial work for what was left by "cp" or "mv"?

Comment: It won't recopy files that have been completely copied, but it will only work on partial files that it has handled itself previously.

Comment: Another question, if a operation by mv fail, will the source file still be the same as before?

Comment: `mv` won't remove anything until it feels that the copy operation has been successful.

Comment: By "it will only work on partial files that it has handled itself previously", do you mean the partial file must be the result of last time failed rsync operation not of mv or cp?

Comment: That is correct. `rsync --partial` uses metadata that it generates in order to figure out where it left off.

Comment: Thanks! My last question: if the partial file was left by mv or cp, rsync --partial will just simply overwrite it. right?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.